# Tensorflow accuracy spikes in every epoch

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running tensorflow on GPU for training. I have a 1 layer GRU cell, with 800 batch size and I do 10 epochs. I see this spikes in the accuracy graph from tensorboard and I do not understand why. See the image. 
[image]

If you count the spikes, they are 10, as the number of epochs. I tried this with different configurations, reducing batch size, increasing number of layers but the spikes are still there. 
You can find the [code here](https://github.com/linnal/DeON-NN) if it helps.

I use tf.RandomShuffleQueue for the data with infinite epochs, and I calculate how many steps it should do. I do not think that the problem is on how I calculate the accuracy ([here](https://github.com/linnal/DeON-NN/blob/master/rnn/model.py#L112)). Do you have any suggestions why this happens?

**EDIT**
min_after_dequeue=2000

Comment: Often this is a symptom of insufficient randomness in the training data. There are a couple of ways to improve this: (1) increase `min_after_dequeue` in the `tf.RandomShuffleQueue` so that examples are sampled from a larger population, (2) read multiple files in parallel (e.g. using `tf.train.shuffle_batch_join()` or `tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave()`) instead of one file at a time.

Comment: Which is the actual value of `min_after_dequeue` that you are using? Please, add it in the original question as an edit. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try point (2) suggested by @mrry. I edit the question with my  `min_after_dequeue` value. Thanks

Comment: How are you computing accuracy? Is this eval accuracy or training accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the same problem from [Tensorflow accuracy spikes in every epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796720/tensorflow-accuracy-spikes-in-every-epoch), but for a custom metric.

I wrote an [answer for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839270/1546737) already, but I can adapt the general idea here.

I couldn't track the exact place where you update/reset your metrics, or where you register them as so. Therefore, I'm assuming this might be done automatically by tensorflow. And if so, I believe the issue you're seeing is caused by a metric artifact due to averaging. You can probably see the per-batch metric by using

```py
def on_batch_begin(batch, logs):
    model.reset_metrics()
    return

lambda_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_batch_begin=on_batch_begin)
```

and passing it when training with

```py
model.fit(..., callbacks=[lambda_callback])
```

Note that this will obviously make all metrics report only the last training batch loss for each epoch.